# What does "100tifiko" mean?

Tags: expresiones, coloquialismos, jerga-internet

I keep seeing the phrase *yo k se, no soy 100tifiko* on Twitter, Facebook and Youtube comments. I understand what means *yo que se, no soy ...* It could be something like *I don't know, I am not ...*, but I can't figure out what *100tifiko* means. I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks in advanance.

Comment: So write idiotic people, don't learn that Spanish: *que* should always be written like that and never, ever *k*.

Comment: A mí me desagrada totalmente cuando las personas echan a perder el idioma de esa forma. Cuál es la diferencia en tiempo de tecleo de "100tifiko" con "científico"? incluso, la forma correcta me salió más rápido teclear :-) Por otro lado, la "k" solo se debe usar en contadas palabras según la RAE. Por qué deformar el idioma usando indiscriminadamente esa letra? La gente se acostumbra a escribir mal, y luego cuando es necesario dar buena impresión, por ejemplo, en algún anuncio o buscando trabajo, no se dan cuenta de que cometen errores.

Comment: No one (at least in Spain) speak like this. It's just a kind of *slang* that is now frequently used in internet or as a joke... but it's not a proper way to speak

Comment: They are just funny Spanish memes. I think these expressions are not used even as slang, just for memes to make fun

Comment: Just spanish version of L33T 5p33ch. Pay it no mind. 100 is 'cien' in spanish, so it's cientifico, meaning scientist.

Comment: There is a [Twitter user with that name](https://twitter.com/100tifiko), and [one on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/user/100tifiko), and a [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/100tifiko) ;-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`100` is `cien`

`cien` + `tífiko` should be slang for `científico` which is `scientist`

So something like `I am not a scientist`...

Answer (score 4):

Its just a funny way of saying scientific (100=cien + tifico). Just like 1000itar means mil+ital = militar. 3.1416loto means pilot (pi+loto).

Remember to always answer a "Pa k kieres saber eso jaja saludos"

These terms are popularized through Instagram and Youtube mainly.

Comment: And twitter, Link [here](https://twitter.com/)

Comment: Then can I say the city `Milan` as `1000An`, Cousin?

Comment: Yes, and 3.1416amonte is Piamonte. Hope it helps

Comment: Hay muchas formas 2.718quival2.718nt2.718s.

Comment: guys, I don´t know you, the pi y understand but `2.718quival2.718nt2.718s` I do not understand, that is to much to think. Could you tell me what this means??

Comment: @Mary the [mathematical constant e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)) is 2.71828

Comment: @JanDoggen thank´s a lot, sometimes this little things scape

Answer (score 4):

Ambas frases, "yo ke no soy un 100tifiko" y "Pa k kieres saber eso jaja saludos", surgieron de respuestas a una pregunta en "Yahoo Answers", página en donde alguien escribe cualquier tipo de pregunta y la gente contesta (similar a ésta pero de temática abierta).

Alguien lo subió a las redes sociales y se hizo "viral".

Por otro lado, nadie dice: "1000itar" o "3.1416loto", por lo menos no aquí en Argentina. "3.1416loto" hasta me costó entender a qué se refería.

Comment: Aquí en España si se dicen ambas (alguno las dice al menos). +1 por poner el origen

Comment: I don't understand U :(

Comment: @Daniela a mi también me costo trabajo lo de "1000itar" o "3.1416loto"